# Find transitive relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Is this relation on $A$ transitive? I know that the relation is reflexive and symmetric but I can not tell if it's transitive.

$\mathcal R =\{(a,a), (a,b), (a,c), (b,a), (b,b), (b,d), (c,a), (c,c), (c,d), (d,b), (d,c), (d,d)\}$

where $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No is is not, $a \mathcal R b$ and $b \mathcal R d$ but $a \mathcal \not R d$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: observe that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,d) \in R$, but $(a,d) \notin R$. What does it mean for a relation to be transitive?